# Archive partition files to target server database form source server database

Tags: sql-server, archive, partition, filegroup

I have two Windows Servers with same SQL Server 2017 software and data model setups. The two databases have the same kind of file group structure too.

The goal is to be able to drop oldest quarter partitions on OLDB from source server and move them to target server on ARDB at the beginning of every new quarter.

Is there any chance to detach `.ndf` from OLDB and attach to ARDB.?

Comment: You can't attach a file with data to existing database. If you want to minimize production impact consider restoring backup of full production database on ARDB, copy data for specific partition and then switch out partition in production.

Comment: thak you for reply. switch out patition will work under same database with same partition schem. right? if i am wrong correct me. here i want to archive old data to different server db. please suggest me best way to done this goal.

Comment: Yes. Same db, same server. So you need to somehow export data from production server or from backup of production/secondary instance before switching out.